# env file is not detected in vscode

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I have a `my-project` multi-root workspace:

```
- my-project
   - my-project-api-gateway
   - another-root-folder-we-dont-care-about
```

Here's my `launch.json` configuration file for `my-project-api-gateway`

```json
{
  // See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launchjson-attributes
  // and variables here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "my-project-api-gateway",
      "type": "go",
      "request": "launch",
      "mode": "debug",
      "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env", ----> Error loading .env file
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/main.go"
    }
  ]
}
```

DEBUG Console Output

```
Starting: /Users/me/go/bin/dlv dap --check-go-version=false --listen=127.0.0.1:53890 --log-dest=3 from /Users/me/path/to/project/src
DAP server listening at: 127.0.0.1:53890
Type 'dlv help' for list of commands.
2022/07/20 10:30:52 Error loading .env file
Process 13526 has exited with status 1
Detaching
dlv dap (13508) exited with code: 0
```

Thanks for your help

---

#### dlv, go, gopls and vscode versions

```
❯ dlv version
Delve Debugger
Version: 1.8.2

❯ go version
go version go1.18 darwin/amd64

❯ gopls -v version
Build info
----------
golang.org/x/tools/gopls v0.9.1

❯ code -v
1.69.2
```

Extension `Go for Visual Studio Code` is v0.35.1

### `Go: Locate Configured Go Tools` output:

```
Checking configured tools....
GOBIN: /Users/me/go/bin
toolsGopath: 
gopath: /Users/me/dev/go
GOROOT: /usr/local/go
PATH: /usr/local/go/bin:/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:/Users/me/.cargo/bin:/Users/me/go/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:/usr/local/cassandra/bin
PATH (vscode launched with): /Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:/Users/me/.cargo/bin:/Users/me/go/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:/usr/local/cassandra/bin

    go: /usr/local/go/bin/go: go version go1.18 darwin/amd64

    gotests:    /Users/me/go/bin/gotests    (version: v1.6.0 built with go: go1.18)
    gomodifytags:   /Users/me/go/bin/gomodifytags   (version: v1.16.0 built with go: go1.18)
    impl:   /Users/me/go/bin/impl   (version: v1.1.0 built with go: go1.18)
    goplay: /Users/me/go/bin/goplay (version: v1.0.0 built with go: go1.18)
    dlv:    /Users/me/go/bin/dlv    (version: v1.8.2 built with go: go1.18)
    golangci-lint:  /Users/me/go/bin/golangci-lint  (version: v1.45.2 built with go: go1.18)
    gopls:  /Users/me/go/bin/gopls  (version: v0.9.1 built with go: go1.18)

go env
Workspace Folder (my-project-api-gateway): /Users/me/dev/back/go/my-project/my-project-api-gateway
    GO111MODULE=""
    GOARCH="amd64"
    GOBIN="/Users/me/go/bin"
    GOCACHE="/Users/me/Library/Caches/go-build"
    GOENV="/Users/me/Library/Application Support/go/env"
    GOEXE=""
    GOEXPERIMENT=""
    GOFLAGS=""
    GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
    GOHOSTOS="darwin"
    GOINSECURE=""
    GOMODCACHE="/Users/me/dev/go/pkg/mod"
    GONOPROXY="github.com/BigBoulard/*"
    GONOSUMDB="github.com/BigBoulard/*"
    GOOS="darwin"
    GOPATH="/Users/me/dev/go"
    GOPRIVATE="github.com/BigBoulard/*"
    GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
    GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
    GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
    GOTMPDIR=""
    GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
    GOVCS=""
    GOVERSION="go1.18"
    GCCGO="gccgo"
    GOAMD64="v1"
    AR="ar"
    CC="clang"
    CXX="clang++"
    CGO_ENABLED="1"
    GOMOD="/Users/me/dev/back/go/my-project/my-project-api-gateway/go.mod"
    GOWORK=""
    CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
    CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
    CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
    CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
    CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
    PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
    GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -arch x86_64 -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/1g/fytltrn578gg3xgp3c_sglhw0000gq/T/go-build1439123167=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick here is that my `.env` is under my workspace folder:  `${workspaceFolder}/.env`, but **delve** doesn't use `${workspaceFolder}` as the **current working directory** that why I'm using `os.Getwd()` to fetch the `.env` from here.

`load_eng.go` excerpt below:

```golang
curDir, err := os.Getwd()
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
loadErr := godotenv.Load(curDir + "/.env")
if loadErr != nil {
  log.Fatalln("can't load env file from current directory: " + curDir)
}
```

So, I just had to set the current working directory `$cwd` by adding `"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"` in my `launch.json` file:

```json
"configurations": [
    {
      "name": "My Application",
      "type": "go",
      "request": "launch",
      "mode": "debug",
      "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/main.go",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  ]
```

**Useful resources:**

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_predefined-variables

https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/wiki/debugging